GCC -Woverride-init warning with anonymous structs in a union
I need to define a type formed with 2 24-bit fields (48 bits in total). I didn't find a way to do it with bitfields in a struct. So I defined my type with a union and 2 anonymous structs :
typedef union
{
    struct __attribute__((packed))
    {
        uint32_t a : 24,
                   :  8;
        uint16_t   : 16;
    };
    struct __attribute__((packed))
    {
        uint16_t   : 16;
        uint32_t   :  8,
                 b : 24;
    };
} myType;

This way I can access a and b directly from a variable of myType:
myType var;
var.a = 0x123456;
var.b = 0x654321;

The issue is when I use an initializer on this type like this:
myType var = {
    .a = 0x123456;
    .b = 0x654321;
};

Here only field b is initialized because a and b are parts of a different part of the union. That's the normal behaviour for the compiler, but it would be useful to have a "override-init" warning.
If I do the same with named structs inside this union, I get that warning :
typedef union
{
    struct __attribute__((packed))
    {
        uint32_t a : 24,
                   :  8;
        uint16_t   : 16;
    } x;
    struct __attribute__((packed))
    {
        uint16_t   : 16;
        uint32_t   :  8,
                 b : 24;
    } y;
} myType;


myType var = {
    .x = { .a = 0x123456 };
    .y = { .b = 0x654321 }; // warning: initialization field overwritten [-Woverride-init]
};

I don't want to have named structs in my code because their names would be artificial (with no meaning). But I would like to have that warning if I make that type of initialization mistake in my code.
Is there a way to have that warning with anonymous fields ?
Or is there a better way to define my type ?

You realize this is an 8 byte large struct and those initializers point at quite different parts of the struct, yeah? On gcc x86_64 then .a = 0x123456 gives 56 34 12 00 00 00 00 00  but .b = 0x654321 gives 00 00 00 00 21 43 65 00. Seems like a broken and very obscure data structure even if you can get it not to partially overwrite some of the contents? How about dropping the bit-fields and just make a 6 byte type like what seems to be intended instead?

Out of interest, what specifically goes wrong when you just definite a struct with two 24-bit fields? Is there a padding or alignment issue or something?

Sorry, I forgot to add attribute((packed)), I edited. The type is 6 bytes large with 2 fields of 3 bytes.

I suspect the 2 x 24-bit integer types are an external representation of the data and not the internal representation?  There is probably an endian requirement as well.  Therefore this question is probably more about marshalling the data.

That data is received from (or sent to) an external bus. But that part is not a problem, the representation I use (union + anonymous types) works well. I'm only afraid that me or someone else in my team uses the initializer thinking this is a regular struct (like a lot of other types in our program) without any warning from the GCC. I think it is strange to have the warning only with named structs because it leads to the same error.

Like I mentioned, that's an issue resolved during the marshalling of the data, when writing it to the bus.  Internally you can use whatever representation of the data that is convenient to you.  Any warnings about size restrictions etc. can be documented on the struct members.

If you use Clang 14 or later and its -std=c2x switch, you can get a six-byte structure with two 24-bit fields with struct __attribute__((__packed__)) { _BitInt(24) a : 24, b : 24; }. Compiler Explorer shows this also works in GCC trunk but not GCC 13.2.

@trojanfoe I don't want marshalling of the data, if I do that, I will have to have a specific code for each message I send/receive to transform it the right way. That's why the type has to match the data sent/received.

@EricPostpischil I must use gcc and -std=c99

@clem822: That is absurd. Nobody should be writing new code to the C 1999 standard in 2024 unless they are supporting a critical platform which needs an update and for which no later compiler is available. And, given that GCC is to be used, the latter is not true.

@EricPostpischil Not my choice, sadly.

GCC and Clang accept the code with the -std=c99 switch.

"I don't want marshalling of the data" That's the proper way to do it. "if I do that, I will have to have a specific code for each message I send/receive to transform it the right way. " No, just one to marshal and one to unmarshal.  Note also you have endianness to worry about.

@dbush Having a type matching exactly the data looks like a proper way to do it. One data => one type. It looks cleaner than one data => one internal type, one external type, one function to marshal from internal to external and one from external to internal. I don't understand how I could have only one function to marshal every type of message I have. For me each different type will need its own marshaling, it will depend on how much space is inserted between 2 fields in the internal representation and it will be different for each type.

It turns out you do not need _BitInt. Clang and GCC accept struct __attribute__((__packed__)) { unsigned a : 24, b : 24; } at least as far back as Clang 4 and GCC 5 and make it a six-byte structure, with -std=c99.

@clem822 And there are no endian requirements on this bus?  It's always the same as the native byte order?

@trojanfoe There is endianness requirement, but I know how to handle it

@EricPostpischil This looks to work well, thanks ! I tried it on my PC, it works, I will try it on the target (not the same compiler).


is there a better way to define my type ?

Yes, just do it yourself.
struct myType {
   uint8_t d[48 / 8];
};

// little endian or big endian?
static long _get24(uint8_t *b) {
   return b[0] << 16 | b[1] << 8 | b[2];
}
static void _set24(uint8_t *b, long v) {
   b[0] = v >> 16;
   b[1] = v >> 8;
   b[2] = v;
}

long myType_get_a(struct myType *t) { return _get24(t->d); }
long myType_get_b(struct myType *t) { return _get24(&t->d[3]); }
void myType_set_a(struct myType *t, long v) { _set24(t->d, v); }
void myType_set_b(struct myType *t, long v) { _set24(&t->d[3], v); }


You cant initialize two members of the union at the same time. You need to have another one:
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint64_t a : 24,
        uint64_t   :  8;
        uint64_t   : 16;
    } x;
    struct
    {
        uint64_t   : 16;
        uint64_t   :  8;
        uint64_t b : 24;
    } y;
    struct
    {
        uint64_t initx : 24;
        uint64_t inity : 24;
    };
} myType;


myType var = {
    .initx = 0x123456 ,
    .inity = 0x654321 
};


That's the point, I don't wat to be able to initialize both fields, I want the compiler to warn me about my error if I write it. In your solution the length of the type will be 64 bits, I want it to be 48 bits.

@clem822 Why does it need to be 48-bits?  There are no 24- or 48-bit types so you will have make do with 2 x 32-bit types (probably in a struct) and provide validation to ensure the values stored do no overrun 24-bits.  You are approaching this issue in the wrong way.

@trojanfoe Because that type represents a data to be sent on a bus, there is no gap between the 2 fields and no padding after, it has to be 48bits large to match the data.

@clem822 I am trying to convey to you that the way the data is laid out externally has nothing to do with how the data is represented internally.  That's where marshalling comes in.  Please take a minute to think about how data in a JSON file, say, is different to how you would represent it within a struct, so that it's in a form that is most convenient for you to manipulate.  Then consider how the data is read and written to the JSON file.  Your problem is no different.

@clem822 Because that type represents a data to be sent on a bus  Write proper, portable, simple, maintainable, and understandable serialization and deserialization functions and don't use non-portable complex kludges for actual data processing.

Bit-fields are problematic because they are non-portable and hard to predict. Plus in this case they need to introduce padding to the struct. __attribute__((packed)) doesn't fix that, the 32 bit type still need to be aligned. It is rather unlikely that you have a machine with 24 bit alignment support also.
One sensible approach here might be to hide the raw representation of the 6 byte that underneath an opaque type so that the caller can't access it directly and create problems with overlapping initializations or what else might cause problems. Simple example:
my_type.h
#ifndef MY_TYPE_H
#define MY_TYPE_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct my_type my_type;

my_type* my_type_create (uint32_t data, bool left_align);

void     my_type_set    (my_type* mt, uint32_t data, bool left_align);

void     my_type_print  (const my_type* mt);

#endif

my_type.c
#include "my_type.h"

struct my_type
{
  uint8_t data [6];
};

my_type* my_type_create (uint32_t data, bool left_align)
{
  static_assert(sizeof(struct my_type)==6, "Unexpected padding detected.");

  my_type* mt = malloc(sizeof *mt);
  if(mt == NULL) return NULL;

  my_type_set(mt, data, left_align);

  return mt;
}

void my_type_set (my_type* mt, uint32_t data, bool left_align)
{
  size_t data_index = left_align ? 0 : 3;
  memcpy(&mt->data[data_index], &data, 3);
}

void my_type_print (const my_type* mt)
{
   const unsigned char* ptr = (const unsigned char*)mt;
   for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(*mt); i++)
     printf("%.2X ", ptr[i]);
   puts("");
}

main.c
#include "my_type.h"

int main() 
{
  my_type* var = my_type_create(0x123456, true);
  my_type_print(var);
  my_type_set(var, 0x654321, false);
  my_type_print(var);
}

Output (little endian):
56 34 12 00 00 00 
56 34 12 21 43 65 

This can be tweaked further to adhere to a certain endiannness. The current example pretty much assumes little endian, the way memcpy was used.
